# ReactRouter passing name of component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use ReactRouter in my application like so:

```jsx
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Match exactly pattern="/" render={() => (
        <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
      )} />
      <Match exactly pattern="/dashboard" render={() => (
        <DashboardPage content={Main} />
      )} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

const DashboardPage = ({ content }) => (
  <div>
    <main>
      {content}
    </main>
  </div>
);

const Main = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
  </div>
);
```

Unfortunately, the Main component isn't being rendered.  The only way to render it is like so `<DashboardPage content={<Main />} />` whereas `<Match exactly pattern="/dashboard" component={Main} />` works just fine.

Comment: No place are you passing Main to be rendered by the router… (in fact, Main isn’t being rendered anywhere here). Where do you intend it to be rendered? By the Router? By DashboardPage?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall so why does `<DashboardPage content={<Main /> } />` render `Main` but `<DashboardPage content={Main} />` does not?  Are they not basically the same?

Comment: @user2840647: React Classes are functions.  The JSX syntax of `< />` is equivalent to calling the function.  It's the same distinction between `console.log` and `console.log()`

Comment: @gravityplanx but that doesn't explain why one syntax renders the component and the other does not... unless I am missing something.

Comment: `console.log` does not execute the function, it simply references it.  `Main` does not execute the component, it simply references it.  If  you want to execute a function, you need to use the correct syntax.  For vanilla js that syntax is `()`.  For JSX that syntax is `< />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to put this as a comment, but it needs formatting, so it gets to be an answer;

JSX is just a set of syntax around javascript.  You're still writing javascript, and all the rules of javascript still apply.

`Main` is a function.  If you type the name of a function, the result will be the function definition.  But in order for a react class to create a component, you need to actually *execute* that function, not just output it's definition.

It's the same as `console.log` vs. `console.log()`.  Type each into your console and see the difference.  The first returns a function, the second gives you the return value of that function.  For react components, the HTML result is the return value of the function.

In my opinion, the best way to modify your code would be as follows:

```
const DashboardPage = ({ Content }) => (
  <div>
    <main>
      <Content />
    </main>
  </div>

);
```

And be sure to capitalize `Content` when setting the props for `DashboardPage` as well.